# how can i echo '<a>' without it making a link?

Tags: php, html

I want to echo the following without the html being executed :

```
<?php echo 'Allowable tags: <a><b>'; ?>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
echo 'Allowable tags: &lt;a&gt;&lt;b&gt;';
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) would work:

```
<?php echo 'Allowable tags: ' . htmlentities('<a><b>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the the special characters to html entities with PHP [**htmlentities()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), like this:

```
<?php echo htmlentities('Allowable tags: <a><b>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use HTML escape characters...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) — Convert special characters to HTML entities.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('Allowable tags: <a><b>'); ?>
```

Output HTML:

```
Allowable tags: &lt;a&gt;&lt;b&gt;
```

Seen as:

> Allowable tags: <a><b>